# Coil former footprint?

Tags: altium, coil, footprint

I am not sure how to make the footprint of this EP10 coil fomer as there is no guidelines in the datasheet. I am meant to assume all EP10 coil former have the same footprint?

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ferroxcube/CSHS-EP10-1S-8P-T/7034266

Comment: You should be able to get it from your coil former manufacturer.

Comment: I found this https://www.milesplatts.co.uk/products/coil-bobbins-for-ferrite-cores/ep-10/plain/ep10h1s08cs-00 which has more details. Hoping it will have the same footprint.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote for this question?

Comment: Lack of research perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to the manufacturer’s website and get the [datasheet](http://ferroxcube.home.pl/prod/assets/ep10.pdf) for the exact part number.

[image: Correct PN]

This is the SMT part, so all info is provided. If you used the THT part you would have to pick your own pad shape and size as no particular ones are recommended.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't able to find this on the website? https://www.ferroxcube.com/en-global/home/index. How did you find it?

Comment: "You’ll have to pick your own pad shape and size" - but isn't that what's shown as the right-most part of the image you posted?

Comment: @asdfex yes, the original image I posted was to the through-hole part, which Ralph kindly corrected to the SMT version.